# What does typename U = equal_to<T> in template mean ? STL equal_to<T> usage

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have been trying to understand this code

```
    template <typename T, typename _Prd = equal_to<T> >
    struct Vector3
    {
    protected:
        T i,j,k;
        _Prd comp;
    public:
        //default constructor
        Vector3(void);

        //explicit constructor
        Vector3(const T& ijk);

        //explicit constructor
        Vector3(const T& i,const T& j,const T& k);

        //copy constructor
        Vector3(const Vector3<T,_Prd>& copy_from);

        //getters
        T I() const;
        T J() const;
        T K() const;

        //setters
        void I(const T& i);
        void J(const T& j);
        void K(const T& k);

        //get magnitude of vector.
        T Magnitude() const;

        //angle between I,J (clockwise)
        T Direction() const;

        //angle between K and I,J
        T Elevation() const;

        //scale vector to 1
        Vector3<T,_Prd>& Normalize();

        //vector scale up-to value
        Vector3<T,_Prd>& Scale(const T& length);

        ...
};
```

I can't understand first statement

```
template <typename T, typename _Prd = equal_to<T> > struct Vector3 {};
```

It's about the usage of `equal_to<T>`, I found the reference from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/equal_to/) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to). But still there isn't anything like this. Thank you for any help to make me understand this part.

**Update:**

After seeing the answers and reading some text book, my question turns to 2 aspects.

**1. Default Template Arguments**

In C++11 we can supply default template arguments to a template.
Example from C++ primer 5th ed. Page 670.

```
#include <functional>
template <typename T, typename F = less<T> >
int compare (const T &v1, const T &v2, F f = F() )
{
    if (f(v1, v2) return -1 ;
    if (f(v2, v1) return 1 ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

And then we use this template as:

```
bool i = compare(0,42) ;
```

The template will use default less function-object class to instantiate.
However, when we use our own objects:

```
Sales_data item(cin), item2(cin) ;
bool j = compare (item, item2, compareIsbn) ;
```

Then F turns to compareIsbn function-object instead.
So that the same happens on my question above, this way will leave an entrance to the user of the template to allow them introducing their own function-object, in this case it is used as comparator.

**2. Predicates**

Check [What is predicate in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921609/what-is-predicate-in-c)

Comment: Looks like a predicate functor that's defaulted to the equivalence of ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::equal_to` is a class template, which provides something like this:

```
bool operator()(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) const { return lhs == rhs; }
```

In other words, it's a function-object class that wraps the ordinary `==` comparator. The point is that `equal_to` can be specialized, and thus provides a non-intrusive way of adding customizability.

On top of that, your template `Vector3` also provides an *intrusive* way of customizing the comparator by way of the second template argument.

Note that predicates are typically *objects*, and not just trait classes. So your container will actually contain a predicate subobject. If the predicate class is default-constructible, this is no problem, but if it isn't then you must normally provide a copy of the predicate in the container constructor.

As a homework assignment, you can think about how you can avoid spending any actual *memory* on the predicate subobject.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it turns to that I have to understand predicate in C++ as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921609/what-is-predicate-in-c. But it would be nice if you can show me more details or examples. So what's the "intrusive way of customizing the comparator by way of the second template argument "?

Comment: @tomriddle_1234: Well, specifying your own comparator class.

Comment: I updated my question, check if my example is right , cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The second template argument _Prd is assigned a default type much like a function can have default values for arguments. STL uses this heavily. have a look at std::basic_string as an example