# What's the predicate in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is predicate in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921609/what-is-predicate-in-c)

When I read the C++ primer, there is a defined term which is **predicate**.

The definition is this :

**Functions that returns a type that can be converted to bool. Often used by the generic algorithms to test elements . predicates used by the library are either unary (taking one argument) or binary(taking two).**

Anyone that returns a type that can be converted to bool can be predicate ! Right? Or there are some other restrictive conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: Imagine you're removing all vowels in a string. Normally, you'd do something similar to (ignoring the `erase` call for simplicity) `std::remove_if(std::begin(str), std::end(str), isVowel);`. In this case, `isVowel` is the predicate, which takes one character and returns true if it's a vowel. You can apply this concept to anything of this nature.

Comment: Formally in C++, there is no definition of what is a predicate, that comes from logic to name parameters from many C++ standard library functions. Like  in `InputIterator find_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred)`. BTW, a **functor** also can be a predicate to be used with those functions.

Comment: @jogojapan Yes. But it had closed. I want to get more informations about it.thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no formal definition of a predicate in the context of C++ (that I know of anyway), but it generally means a function that can be used in a true/false context.

Here's a possible implementation of [count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) from cppreference that illustrates what it's talking about:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
    count_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first)) {
            ret++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`p` must return something that can be used inside of an `if` statement is what it basically boils down to.

For example:

```
class T {};

T f(int x)
{
    return T();
}
```

This is not a valid predicate for count_if because T is not implicitly convertible to a bool.

In other words:

```
if (f(4)) { }
```

Is uncompilable code.

If, however, T could be implicitly converted to a bool, `f` would be an acceptable predicate (though very odd).