# C++ Checking String

Tags: c++

Say I am taking a string in and want to check whether or not it has a capital letter in the string. I input the string from a file. How would I go about breaking it down to check to see if it has an uppercase value using the ascii values? Thanks!

Comment: `std::find_if`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Please add what you have tried, and what piece of code is giving you trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I cannot think of anything other than possibly taking it in as an array of characters, but that is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C++ algorithm library to find if a string contains an uppercase value in it by using a predicate (using a wrapper version of std::isupper):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool IsUpper (char c) {
    return std::isupper(c);
}

bool hasUpperCase (std::string str) {
    std::string::iterator it = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), IsUpper);
    if (it != str.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "This contains an uppercase character in it...";
    if (hasUpperCase(s)) {
        std::cout << "String s contains a least one uppercase character." << std::endl; 
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "String s does not contain any uppercase character." << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921826/866930) a predicate is:

> is a C++ function returning boolean or instance of object having bool
>   operator() member. Unary predicate take one agrument, binary - two,
>   etc. Examples of questions predicate can answer for particular
>   algorithm are:
>
> - Is this element is what we are looking for?
> - Is the first of two arguments is ordered first in our order?
> - Are the two arguments equal?
>
> Almost all STL algorithms take predicate as last argument.

So, in summary, this works by each character in the string against the predicate function: `IsUpper` which itself uses `std::isupper` to do the checking to see if the character in question is uppercase or not. If it is, it returns true, and that character is stored in the iterator.

REFERENCES:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921826/866930

Comment: You need to actually check if the find succeeded.

Comment: Checking if `std::find_if` succeeded consists of comparing the returned iterator to the end iterator.  Blindly dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior when a match is not found. Also, what you have now is even less correct than before.  Because in addition to the blind dereference, now you are returning a `char` from a function whose return type is `bool`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: correct on all counts. Re-edited. Thanks for the feedback, though - I appreciate it.

Comment: Still wrong.  Let me repeat. Checking if `std::find_if` succeeded consists of comparing the returned iterator to the end iterator. Blindly dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior when a match is not found.  Read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) you provided a link to.  There is an example at the bottom.  It uses `std::find` instead of `std::find_if`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Ah! I see your point. Edited (hopefully for the last time). Thank you for your patience.